# How to verify JavaScript function has called or not in blazer unit testing using moq, Bunit, Xunit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, blazor-webassembly, bunit

I have a js function.

```
function scrollIntoView(elementId) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (elem) {
    elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    window.location.hash = elementId;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and I use this function here, when I click the text I have to scroll to a particular section.

```
public async Task AnchorOnClickAsync(string elementId)
{
    var result = await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>("scrollIntoView", elementId);
}
```

Now I want to test,AnchorOnClickAsync method, the javascript function called or not.

```
  [Fact]
        public async Task MyComponent_Calls_InvokeVoidAsync()
        {
            // Arrange
            var elementId = "personal-details";

            var ctx = new Bunit.TestContext();

            var jsRuntime = new Mock<IJSRuntime>();
            //navigation manager arrange
            var navMan = ctx.Services.GetRequiredService<FakeNavigationManager>();
            // Create an instance of ParentComponent using the mock service and child component
            var cut = new CreateParticipant(
                        mockMainLayoutService.Object,
                        mockIParticipantService.Object,
                        mockSnackbar.Object,
                        mockLookupService.Object,
                        navMan,
                        jsRuntimeMock.Object
            );
            // Act
            await cut.AnchorOnClickAsync("elementId");

            // Assert
            ctx.JSInterop.VerifyInvoke("scrollIntoView", elementId);

        }
```

But I got

```
Outcome: Failed
Error Message:
Bunit.JSInvokeCountExpectedException : VerifyInvoke failed: personal-details
```

Expected number of calls: 1
Actual number of calls:   0

Why I could not invoke the javaScript function